# How to reload the disposed database in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sql-server-ce, datacontext

I want to delete the sqlce database I'm using in my app. So, I disposed to delete it, and I did delete operation via the following code:

```
MyDB.Dispose();
if (myStore.FileExists("MyAppDB.sdf"))
{
    myStore.DeleteFile("MyAppDB.sdf");
}
```

And I replaces new database with the same table, via following code.

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream myStream = myStore.CreateFile("MyAppDB.sdf");
myStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
myStream.Close();
```

Everything goes perfect. But after replacing the database, I can't be able to access my data in the database. The App shows below exception. But If the closed the app open it again, no error/exception comes.

<[image](http://i.cubeupload.com/1Ih3ZA.png) that shows exception> http://i.cubeupload.com/1Ih3ZA.png

I need to know how to replace the database and access the datas without reopening the app ?

How to reload the object/database after I disposed it ?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? Are you using LINQ to SQL or opening it some other way?

Comment: @Justin Using LINQ to SQL

Comment: What scope does MyDB have? Seems it is hloding on to some resources, even after being Disposed (and before Garbage Collection kicks in). Maybe GC.Collect() ?